# How to handle errors when extracting data from untyped JSON in serde_json?

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

I have a `serde_json::Value` which I expect to contain an array of objects. From those objects I want to extract 2 values and return an error if anything fails. This is my code so far:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use anyhow::Result;


fn get_stock(response: serde_json::Value) -> Result<HashMap<String, u32>>{
    response["products"]
        .as_array()?.iter()
        .map(|product| {
            let product = product.as_object()?;
            (
                product["name"].as_str()?.to_owned(),
                //as_u64 fails for some reason
                product["stock"].as_str()?.parse::<u32>()?,
            )
        })
        .collect()?
}
```

When I used `.unwrap()` this worked fine, but after changing the return type to `Result` and replacing unwraps with `?` I'm getting the following compilation errors:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used on `Result`s, not `Option`s, in a function that returns `Result`
  --> src/bin/products.rs:7:20
   |
5  | / fn get_stock(response: serde_json::Value) -> Result<HashMap<String, u32>>{
6  | |     response["products"]
7  | |         .as_array()?.iter()
   | |                    ^ use `.ok_or(...)?` to provide an error compatible with `Result<HashMap<std::string::String, u32>, anyhow::Error>`
8  | |         .map(|product| {
...  |
16 | |         .collect()?
17 | | }
   | |_- this function returns a `Result`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Option<Infallible>>` is not implemented for `Result<HashMap<std::string::String, u32>, anyhow::Error>`
   = note: required by `from_residual`

error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/bin/products.rs:9:46
   |
8  |           .map(|product| {
   |  ______________-
9  | |             let product = product.as_object()?;
   | |                                              ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `(std::string::String, u32)`
10 | |             (
11 | |                 product["name"].as_str()?.to_owned(),
...  |
14 | |             )
15 | |         })
   | |_________- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Option<Infallible>>` is not implemented for `(std::string::String, u32)`
   = note: required by `from_residual`

error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/bin/products.rs:11:41
   |
8  |           .map(|product| {
   |  ______________-
9  | |             let product = product.as_object()?;
10 | |             (
11 | |                 product["name"].as_str()?.to_owned(),
   | |                                         ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `(std::string::String, u32)`
...  |
14 | |             )
15 | |         })
   | |_________- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Option<Infallible>>` is not implemented for `(std::string::String, u32)`
   = note: required by `from_residual`

error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/bin/products.rs:13:42
   |
8  |           .map(|product| {
   |  ______________-
9  | |             let product = product.as_object()?;
10 | |             (
11 | |                 product["name"].as_str()?.to_owned(),
12 | |                 //as_u64 fails for some reason
13 | |                 product["stock"].as_str()?.parse::<u32>()?,
   | |                                          ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `(std::string::String, u32)`
14 | |             )
15 | |         })
   | |_________- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Option<Infallible>>` is not implemented for `(std::string::String, u32)`
   = note: required by `from_residual`

error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/bin/products.rs:13:58
   |
8  |           .map(|product| {
   |  ______________-
9  | |             let product = product.as_object()?;
10 | |             (
11 | |                 product["name"].as_str()?.to_owned(),
12 | |                 //as_u64 fails for some reason
13 | |                 product["stock"].as_str()?.parse::<u32>()?,
   | |                                                          ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `(std::string::String, u32)`
miav@battlestation catbot % cargo run --bin products
   Compiling catbot v0.1.0 (/Users/miav/Documents/Personal/Projects/programming/catbot)
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used on `Result`s, not `Option`s, in a function that returns `Result`
  --> src/bin/products.rs:7:20
   |
5  | / fn get_stock(response: serde_json::Value) -> Result<HashMap<String, u32>>{
6  | |     response["products"]
7  | |         .as_array()?.iter()
   | |                    ^ use `.ok_or(...)?` to provide an error compatible with `Result<HashMap<std::string::String, u32>, anyhow::Error>`
8  | |         .map(|product| {
...  |
16 | |         .collect()?
17 | | }
   | |_- this function returns a `Result`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Option<Infallible>>` is not implemented for `Result<HashMap<std::string::String, u32>, anyhow::Error>`
   = note: required by `from_residual`

error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/bin/products.rs:9:46
   |
8  |           .map(|product| {
   |  ______________-
9  | |             let product = product.as_object()?;
   | |                                              ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `(std::string::String, u32)`
10 | |             (
11 | |                 product["name"].as_str()?.to_owned(),
...  |
14 | |             )
15 | |         })
   | |_________- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Option<Infallible>>` is not implemented for `(std::string::String, u32)`
   = note: required by `from_residual`

error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/bin/products.rs:11:41
   |
8  |           .map(|product| {
   |  ______________-
9  | |             let product = product.as_object()?;
10 | |             (
11 | |                 product["name"].as_str()?.to_owned(),
   | |                                         ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `(std::string::String, u32)`
...  |
14 | |             )
15 | |         })
   | |_________- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Option<Infallible>>` is not implemented for `(std::string::String, u32)`
   = note: required by `from_residual`

error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/bin/products.rs:13:42
   |
8  |           .map(|product| {
   |  ______________-
9  | |             let product = product.as_object()?;
10 | |             (
11 | |                 product["name"].as_str()?.to_owned(),
12 | |                 //as_u64 fails for some reason
13 | |                 product["stock"].as_str()?.parse::<u32>()?,
   | |                                          ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `(std::string::String, u32)`
14 | |             )
15 | |         })
   | |_________- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Option<Infallible>>` is not implemented for `(std::string::String, u32)`
   = note: required by `from_residual`

error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/bin/products.rs:13:58
   |
8  |           .map(|product| {
   |  ______________-
9  | |             let product = product.as_object()?;
10 | |             (
11 | |                 product["name"].as_str()?.to_owned(),
12 | |                 //as_u64 fails for some reason
13 | |                 product["stock"].as_str()?.parse::<u32>()?,
   | |                                                          ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `(std::string::String, u32)`
14 | |             )
15 | |         })
   | |_________- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, ParseIntError>>` is not implemented for `(std::string::String, u32)`
   = note: required by `from_residual`

error: aborting due to 5 previous errors
```

I don't know the exact structure of the JSON in advance, so I cannot parse it into a struct. All I know is that it is most likely an array of objects which have a `name` string field and a `stock` integer field, which I want to extract into a map. If that doesn't happen to be the case, then I want to return an error. What is the simplest way to do this?

UPDATE:
After following Lagerbaer's suggestions and doing some digging I came up with the following solution.

```
use anyhow::{anyhow, Result};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get_stock(response: serde_json::Value) -> Result<HashMap<String, u32>> {
    response
        .get("products")
        .ok_or(anyhow!("'products' not found"))?
        .as_array()
        .ok_or(anyhow!("'products' is not an array"))?
        .iter()
        .map(|product| -> Result<(String, u32)> {
            let product = product.as_object().unwrap();
            Ok((
                product
                    .get("name")
                    .ok_or(anyhow!("'name' not found"))?
                    .as_str()
                    .ok_or(anyhow!("'name' is not a string"))?
                    .trim()
                    .to_owned(),
                //as_u64 fails for some reason
                product
                    .get("stock")
                    .ok_or(anyhow!("'stock' not found"))?
                    .as_str()
                    .ok_or(anyhow!("'stock' is not a string"))?
                    .parse::<u32>()?,
            ))
        })
        .collect()
}
```

Used `ok_or()` to map `Option` to `Result`, had to use the `anyhow!` macro to make it compatible with the anyhow result type.
It also turns out that `collect()` actually accepts an iterator of
`Result<(String, u32)>` to produce a `Result<HashMap<String, u32>>` with the exact behavior I wanted, that is, returning the first error or the complete hash map if there were no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there's a couple issues here and the compiler tries its best to tell you.

I'll get you started on the first, and then I encourage you to try going it alone for a bit.

So the very first error is that, apparently, `as_array` returns an `Option` and not `Result` and, hence, you can't use the `?` operator there.

Luckily, the compiler tells you what to do: `Option` has a method `ok_or` that you should call. It will turn the `Option` into `Result`. If the `Option` is `Some(value)` you'll get a `Ok(value)`, and if the `Option` is `None`, you'll get whatever error you specified in the `ok_or` argument.

Another easy to spot mistake is this: Your function returns a `Result`, so the return value should, obviously, be a `Result`. Hence the very final last `?` should be removed, because that `?` would take a `Result` and turn it into the "pure" value (if the result was `Ok`).

And then what's left is to figure out exactly what the closure should return. Maybe you can try that after fixing the other mistakes that I explained above.